# Is there anything to find the guild id from a message or the channel the message was sent? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Mine, is a funny bot made for my classmates' server. I have two or three servers where the bot is, but when I tried it not to sent messages, it wasn't able to send message neither in other server (though this is logical).

My idea was creating an array with ids of the guilds the bot wasn't able to talk in, and then, send the message only if the guild id wasn't part of that array. logically, I think there is anything wrong, I don't have to make this bot public, it's just for some friends, so I would not create multiple threads for each server.

My question is, are there any ways to get the guild id from a message sent from a user or from the channel the message was sent from? or, are there other easier ways of getting the guild's id?

Answer (score 2):

`discord.Message` has a bunch of attributes, the ones you're asking for are:

- [`discord.Message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild) - returns a `discord.Guild` instance (has an `id` attribute)
- [`discord.Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel) - returns a `discord.Messageable`  instance that also has an `id` attribute

So, let's say you're using an `on_message` event, to get the guild ID:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    guild_id = message.guild.id
```

To get the channel ID:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    channel_id = message.channel.id
```

If you're using commands, the `Context` attributes are the same

```py
guild_id = ctx.guild.id
channel_id = ctx.channel.id
```

Also these are basics OOP concepts, you should already know that if you're messing with discord bots - my suggestion, learn more python.

#### Reference:

- [`Message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)
- [`Guild.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.id)
- [`Channel.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.id)